# node-prune crash build in Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile

I've use `node-prune` in my dockerfile configuration to remove all unnecessary files after `yarn install` and to reduce image size like below:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.15

RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -sf https://gobinaries.com/tj/node-prune | sh

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install --production=true
RUN yarn global add typescript
RUN node-prune

COPY . .

RUN tsc -p tsconfig.build.json
```

but during builing, `tsc` throw me this stack:

```
> [server-builder 10/10] RUN tsc -p tsconfig.build.json:
#26 5.940 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'body-parser'.
#26 5.940   The file is in the program because:
#26 5.940     Entry point for implicit type library 'body-parser'
#26 5.942 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'component-emitter'.
#26 5.942   The file is in the program because:
#26 5.942     Entry point for implicit type library 'component-emitter'
#26 5.942 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'compression'.
#26 5.942   The file is in the program because:
... and many more
```

but when I remove `RUN node-prune` from my Dockerfile then everything is ok and image is successfully builded.

Can someone tell me why `node-prune` crash my build and how to resolve this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: node-prune is removing your devDependencies, you probably have the @types there

Comment: I replace @types to dependencies but error still exists